# JavaScript "this" keyword different behavior based on property name

Tags: javascript, html

While [learning javascript](https://javascript.info/object-methods#internals-reference-type), I have come across(made) an example that has a difference in behavior depending on property name.

- In case 1 it prints undefined (which is understandable)
- In case 2 it prints either nothing (FF 54) or some unusual code (seen when running this script)

**The Question**

Why is there a different behavior when the property name is changed?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>tests</title>
  <script>
    "use strict";
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>Case 1 <br>
      <script>
        let myAbstractObject2 = {
          text1: "someText",
          someMethod1() {
            document.write(`[Output] text1 = ${this.text1}!<br>`);
          }
        };

        myAbstractObject2.someMethod1();

        (true ? myAbstractObject2.someMethod1 : null)();
      </script>
    </li>
    <li>Case 2 <br>
      <script>
        let myAbstractObject3 = {
          name: "someText",
          someMethod1() {
            document.write(`[Output] name = ${this.name}!<br>`);
          }
        };

        myAbstractObject3.someMethod1();

        (true ? myAbstractObject3.someMethod1 : null)();
      </script>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible its taking the name property from the li object? Do you get the same results if you use say name2 or text2?

Comment: @Tommy the property is taken from `window`, see [window.name](//mdn.io/window.name)

Comment: @UlysseBN ok cool, so I had the right idea just the wrong object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case number 2, `this.name` will refer to [window.name](//mdn.io/window.name). That's why you get a GUID.

It is basically the same as case 1 (`this` boils down to window global attribute), except that you used a keyword which is a defined property of your window global attribute.

Comment: @naaz does this answer suits your question?

Comment: I haven't made it far enough in the tutorial to fully understand the answer. but it does make sense.